# Angular optimization of large form

Tags: jquery, angularjs, optimization

I have a form with 800 questions, which look like the one below:

```
<div class="question hide" id="name_firsteng">

    <p>Please tell me what is your full first name(s)? E.g. John Peter</p>

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-8 col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3">
            <input type="text" name="name_firsteng" class="form-control" ng-model="::vm.questionnaire.name_firsteng" ng-required="true" />
        </div>
    </div>

</div>
```

I use the `.hide` class to show one question at a time with Jquery.

This runs fine on a desktop, but on a tablet it's a bit sluggish. As you can see I've used one-time binding on all the `ng-models`, but this hasn't helped much.

If I look in Chrome's Timeline in Dev Tools, there's a function call that takes about a second to complete if I just click on a radio button. The function is line 3403, which is the second line below:

```
function createEventHandler(element, events) {
  var eventHandler = function(event, type) {
    // jQuery specific api
    event.isDefaultPrevented = function() {
      return event.defaultPrevented;
    };

    var eventFns = events[type || event.type];
    ...
```

I'm a bit stuck now: I'm not sure what this function does or why it's called or what to do to try optimize this. I don't think it's Jquery related as I've put timers into my code (that hides/unhides) and that runs fast enough. So I suspect it's more to do with angular and the model/digest/binding.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Why not use angular to manage the show/hides? It has directives built in specifically for that with `ng-show`, `ng-hide`, and `ng-if`.

Comment: Firstly, I dont think that Jquery is causing the performance issue because the sluggishness is when the model changes, not when the Jquery code runs. Secondly I think all those directives you'd be adding with `ng-show/hide/if`: wouldn't they all required watches which would make the performance worse?

Comment: Just a suggestion based on you pointing to code that is taking 1 second (that is jquery related). It's easy enough to just use angular and not use another external library for stuff like you are doing also, more external deps slows things as well. There would be one watcher if you set it up right, show/hide just toggles a display: none on the css. It would be helpful to see how this is set up in angular to really see what is slow about it. Is it one big object? Where are the questions coming from? Does that object have functions running on it, or maybe have a model over it?

Comment: It turns out it's because there is just so many DOM elements involved at any one time. So I changed all the `.hide` classes to `ng-if="vm.currentQuestion.name === 'name_firsteng'"` (or whatever the current question's name is). This means there's only one question element in the DOM at any time, and it's now blazing fast again. Thanks @ajmajmajma for the suggestions. I'm not sure if this means I am plenty of watches or just 1 as you suggest though.

Comment: ng-if removes the item completely from the dom, so that makes sense. Glad I could help!